# Formatting only named fields with str.format_map()

Tags: python, format

I'm familiar with the usual ways to avoid missing fields causing problems when formatting a string. For example:

```
class SafeMap(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return f'{{{key}}}'


s = '{a}{b}'.format_map(SafeMap({'a': 1}))
print(s)
```

Result:

```
'1{b}'
```

However, I have a case where I want to apply a partial map like in the example, but the string also contains positional fields, for example:

```
s = '{a}{}{b}'.format_map(SafeMap({'a': 1}))
print(s)
```

Causes a `ValueError: Format string contains positional fields` due to there not being a value provided to replace the positional field between `{a}` and `{b}`.

My question: without manually parsing the entire string myself, is there a reliable way to perform a partial `.format_map()` on a string that leaves both unmatched named fields and positional fields alone?

(either all of them, or perhaps it only fills the ones that are not provided with a value - but I'm specifically after a case where it simply does not touch positional fields)

That is when running:

```
s = '{a}{}{b}'.format_map(SomeMagicClass({'a': 1}))
```

I need the result to be:

```
1{}{b}
```

And I need the solution to work reliably for any formattable string, not just this trivial case. If you know of a reliable solution that doesn't use a class, I'd be happy with that as well, the class-based solution is only presented as an example because it is a common solution.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up with myself:

```
from string import Formatter


def partial_format_map(s, d):
    return ''.join(lit + (
        Formatter().convert_field(
            Formatter().format_field(self.globals[key], fmt), conv) if key in self.globals else
        '' if key is None else
        f'{{{key}{":" + fmt if fmt else ""}{":" + conv if conv else ""}}}'
    ) for lit, key, fmt, conv in Formatter().parse(value))
```

This works fairly well, but I'd be happy to accept a better answer - especially if someone sees fault with this solution.